# Query to find if a foreign key is set

Tags: mysql

OK, I have two MySQL Tables:

**TableA** containing the following columns: **idTableA** and **idTableB_FK**

**TableB** containing the following columns: **idTableB** and **idTableA_FK**

The relationships are as follows:

1. One-to-Many relationship from TableA to TableB (**TableA.idTableA** is
   the PK, and the FK for that relationship is **TableB.idTableA_FK**)
2. One-to-One relationship between TableA and TableB (**TableB.idTableB**
   is the PK, and it is be represented in **TableA.idTableB_FK**). It is
   a one-to-one relationship because you can only have one row in TableA to take a
   foreign key value.

Assuming the following data in **TableA**

```
idTableA     |    idTableB_FK
-----------------------------
    1        |       2
    2        |       5
    3        |       6
    4        |       8
```

And the folloing in **TableB**

```
idTableB     |    idTableA_FK
------------------------------
    1        |       1
    2        |       1
    3        |       2
    4        |       2
    5        |       2
    6        |       3
    7        |       3
    8        |       4
```

Now, what I want a query that will display idTableA, idTableB, and will display is_set column. The is set is a yes/no field (or 1/0) where it is set to yes only if **TableA.idTableB_FK** has a corresponding set value for that FK. So for the above example:

```
idTableA    |    idTableB    |     is_set
---------------------------------------------
    1       |       1        |       no
    1       |       2        |       yes
    2       |       3        |       no
    2       |       4        |       no
    2       |       5        |       yes
    3       |       6        |       yes
    3       |       7        |       no
    4       |       8        |       yes
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
SELECT b.idTableA_FK, b.idTableB ,

IF (
    (SELECT a.idTableB_FK 
        FROM (TableA AS a) 
        WHERE a.idTableA = b.idTableA_FK
    ) = b.idTableB, TRUE, FALSE
) AS is_set

FROM (TableB AS b)
```

Which produced the correct results.

I like to thank all that responded, and I am voting up [fthiella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833073/fthiella) because his/her suggested solution was influential to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select
  TableA.idTableA,
  TableB.idTableB,
  case when EXISTS(select null
              from TableA TableA_1
              where
                TableA_1.idTableA = TableA.idTableA
                and TableA_1.idTableB_FK = TableB.idTableB)
  then 'yes' else 'no' end as is_set
from
  TableB left join TableA
  on TableB.idTableA_FK = TableA.idTableA
```

Answer (score 0):

OK that was from memory but should do it. If it is wrong I can run it against something and fix it.

```
SELECT tb.idTableA_FK AS idTableA, tb.idTableB, tbb.idTableB IS NOT NULL AS is_set 
    FROM TableB AS tb LEFT JOIN TableA AS ta ON (tb.idTableA_FK = ta.idTableA) 
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS tbb ON (ta.idTableB_FK = tbb.idTableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.idTableA, b.idTableB, c.idTableB_FK IS NOT NULL is_set
FROM TableA a, TableB b LEFT JOIN TableA c ON b.idTableB=c.idTableB_FK
WHERE b.idTableA_FK=a.idTableA
```